# Proving in different ways that $n^{n-1}-1$ is divisible by $(n-1)^2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, geometric-series

I have this amazing exercise which explicitly says prove in at least six different way that 
$n^{n-1}-1$ is divisible by $(n-1)^2$ where $n$ is an integer.

So far I have only prove it as follows: By geometric sum we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}n^k=\frac{n^{n-1}-1}{n-1}$$
However, since $n\equiv 1\mod (n-1)$ we have 
$$\frac{n^{n-1}-1}{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}n^k\equiv \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}1^k\mod(n-1)$$
that is $$\frac{n^{n-1}-1}{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}n^k\equiv n-1\mod(n-1)\Longleftrightarrow  \frac{n^{n-1}-1}{n-1} \equiv 0\mod(n-1)$$

and this prove that $(n-1)^2$ divides $n^{n-1}-1$.

> Does anyone have another approach different from mine.?
>   Note that I do necessary need one to give all six approaches as was asked in the exercise one or two is plainly enough for me.

Comment: You describe the question as "amazing". I would describe it as a complete waste of time.

Comment: @RobArthan you are right

Comment: six different ways seems both vague and arbitrary, to me.

Comment: @fleablood you are right

Comment: I'm not opposed to "Prove in different ways if possible" but tedious little proofs each with a minor change seems pointless.

Comment: @fleablood you are right

Comment: So now you have 6 answers. Who is going to waste their time working out whether they are "different"? I'm voting to close this,

Comment: @RobArthan you are right

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a challenge to come up with 6 different proofs of a simple number-theoretic fact has no pedagogical value.

Comment: @RobArthan you are right

Comment: @RobArthan Would you still vote to close if the OP removed the reference to "*six*" different ways? Other than (maybe) that, this is IMHO a perfectly legitimate and well asked question, like is often demanded of others on MSE: it is clearly articulated and typeset, the OP put forward their own work etc.

Comment: Is there a combinatorial argument for $n^2 \mid (n+1)^n-1$? Haven't got time to look for one. The binomial proof might hint at one.

Comment: @jkabrg I dont get your point please elaborate

Comment: @GuyFsone https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_proof

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding by the binomial theorem,
$$(k+1)^{n-1}-1=k^{n-1}+\binom{n-1}1k^{n-2}+\cdots+\binom{n-1}2k^2+\binom{n-1}1k\ .$$
Now substitute $k=n-1$.

- The last term on the RHS is $(n-1)k=(n-1)^2$ which is obviously a multiple of $(n-1)^2$.
- Every other term is a multiple of $k^2$, which is $(n-1)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Write $n^{n-1}-1$ in base $n$. It consists of $n-1$ digits that are all the digit $n-1$.

So we can divide by $n-1$ once. The quotient is obviously also a repdigit, consisting of $n-1$ ones.

Now, a number in base $n$ is divisible by $n-1$ exactly if its digital sum is divisible by $n-1$. But the repunit from the previous step has digital sum $n-1$. So we can divide by $n-1$ once more!

---

*In some sense this is the same as what you're already doing, but it is arguably a different way of* thinking *about it, so it may qualify as a different proof.*

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
n^{n-1}-1 &= (n-1) ( n^{n-2} \color{red}{- 1} + n^{n-3} \color{red}{- 1} +\ldots + n^2 \color{red}{- 1} + n \color{red}{- 1} + 1 \color{red}{+n-2}) \\
 &= (n-1) \big(\,(n-1)(\ldots) + (n-1)(\ldots)+ \ldots + (n-1)(n+1)+ (n-1)+ (n-1))\,\big)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Binomial theorem:

$$n^{n-1}=(1+(n-1))^{n-1}=1+\binom{n-1}{1}(n-1)^1+\binom{n-1}{2}(n-1)^2\cdots\equiv 1\pmod{(n-1)^2}$$

More generally:

> If $a\equiv 1\pmod m$ then $a^m\equiv 1\pmod{m^2}.$

Answer (score 1):

Set $P(x)=x^{n-1}-1$.

- We have $P(1)=1^{n-1}-1=0$, so $P(x)=(x-1)Q(x)$ for some polynomial $Q(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$.
- We also have $P'(1)=(n-1)1^{n-2}=n-1$ i.e. $n-1$ is the remainder of division of $P'(x)$ by $x-1$, i.e. $(x-1)Q'(x)+Q(x)=P'(x)=(x-1)R(x)+n-1$ for some polynomial $R(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$.

Now, by multiplying by $x-1$, we get: $(x-1)^2Q'(x)+P(x)=(x-1)^2R(x)+(x-1)(n-1)$. Now set $x=n$ and we get: $n^{n-1}-1=P(n)=(n-1)^2(R(n)-Q'(n)+1)$ - divisible by $(n-1)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$n^{n-1}-1=(n-1)(n^{n-2}+n^{n-3}+...+n+1)$$

then dividing

$$\frac{n^{n-2}+n^{n-3}+...+n+1}{n-1}$$

it can be shown that at each step the remainder is

$$2n^{n-3}+n^{n-4}+...+n+1$$
$$3n^{n-4}+n^{n-3}+...+n+1$$
$$...$$
$$(n-2)n+1$$
$$(n-1)\cdot1$$

Comment: It's much easier to just note that $\frac{n^k-1}{n-1}$ is an integer, so the numerator is congruent to $1+1+\dots+1\pmod{(n-1)}$, and hence the quotient is an integer. But that's the OPs original argument, I guess.

Comment: Yes indeed the OP is looking for different approches, this one is very elementary but it works fine.